# "Almost none" + plural verb

Tags: adverbs, pronouns, verb-agreement

> When none is modified by *almost* it is difficult to avoid
> treating the word as a plural: *Almost none of the officials were interviewed by the committee*.
>
> https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=none

Why does *almost* trigger the plural agreement of the verb?

Comment: How many is *"almost none"*? It must be more than "none" - it is therefore assumed to be a reference to a small number greater than one because if that number were **one**, then **one** would be used.

Comment: A thought, so not given as an 'answer'. 'None of them was present' echoes 'Not [a single] one of them was present' whereas 'None of them were present' echoes (rather less directly) 'No [subset {taking notional agreement} of the] people were present'. 'Almost none' echoes 'very few' not 'just one' for count usages.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth could you please elaborate the part _subset {taking notional agreement}_?  Ngram for _almost none are/is_: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&content=almost+none+is%2C+almost+none+are&smoothing=3&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&direct_url=t4%3B%2Calmost%20none%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Balmost%20none%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAlmost%20none%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Calmost%20none%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Balmost%20none%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAlmost%20none%20are%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I was compressing <<  [I'm hypothesising] ''None of them were present' echoes (those choosing this usage either consciously or subconsciously modelling on) (rather less directly than the previous usage) 'No people were present', 'No royalty were present', 'No staff were involved' (as well as the more obvious plural-agreement-triggers such as with 'No asymptomatic patients were involved.') >>

Comment: *Almost none of the cake was eaten*. It's the fact that *officials* is a plural countable noun that triggers the plural agreement, not *almost*.

Comment: @PeterShor Obviously also for uncountable ones: _(almost) none (of the water) was drunk_